# Positioning below the first image without removing from the list tag

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to position the second image below the first image without removing either image from the list tag. For example using CSS to display the image two below the first image?

Below is my markup

```
<ul>
   <li>
    <img id="img1" src="imageone.png">
    <img id="img2" src="imagetwo.png">  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what about `<br>` tag?

Comment: thanks @Lashane didnt realise it was something so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use CSS like you said, you could give the IDs a display of block so they sit on their own.

```
#img1, #img2 {
  display: block;
}
```